# Can someone give a quick explanation of what this exercise wants from me?

Tags: graph-theory

I am having trouble understanding exercise 1.25 from the picture below.

[image]

I know what order means, but the second sentence puzzles me. I have included the exercises before it in the case that 1.25 makes sense in their context, but I doubt it.

Comment: I think it's just a typo.

Comment: But what did the authors wanted to say ? Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the question is to prove that at most, one of $G$ and the **complement** of $G$ are bipartite (at least if that's what you denote by $\overline G$).

Comment: Here's a solution: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1124564/complement-of-a-bipartite-graph

Answer (score 3):

The question is likely asking you to prove that at most one of $G$ and $\overline{G}$ is bipartite.

If a bipartite graph $G$ has order 5 or more, by the pigeonhole principle one of the "parts" has at least 3 vertices. This means that $\overline{G}$ has $K_3$ as a subgraph, so $\overline{G}$ is not bipartite.